# Is there a function in flutter that returns true when the status bar is visible?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-layout, android-developer-api

I know you can hide status bar using this code:`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])`
But when a notification pops up the status bar is visible again how to know if it's visible and hide it again?

Answer (score 0):

It would probably work with `SystemChrome.setSystemUIChangeCallback`:

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _isFullScreen = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIChangeCallback((systemOverlaysAreVisible) async =>
        setState(() => _isFullScreen = systemOverlaysAreVisible));
  }
  ...
}
```

Note that `systemOverlaysAreVisible` reflects the state **before** the UI change.